# Round numbers to multiples of 10 by saving the first 2 digits and replacing the rest with 0

Tags: c

I need to round off the following numbers and retain the first two digits to do further calculations.I can't use the while neither the for.
I don't know how to do it, can anyone help me?

```
438332 = 430000
56322 = 56000
1256489 = 1200000
```

Comment: Do you need to do further calculations with the rounded-down numbers or is it only for display? In the latter case you could `sprintf` the number to a string and replace all characters from the 3rd to the end. Please [edit] your question to provide requested information or clarification, don't use comments for this purpose.

Comment: If you have the strange requirement not to use `while` or `for`, you could use `if` in combination with `goto` or recursion. Please read all comments and reply by updating your question accordingly. Show how you would implement it using a `while` or `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a recursive function so that it does not use `while` or `for` (what a ***stupid*** requirement!!)

The routine below keeps dividing the number by 10, until `n` only has 2 digits left (`n < 100`), while tracking how many `0`'s to put on the number.

For example, when the problem is `438332`, at the base of the recursion, `n = 43`, and the calling functions will multiple by `10000`, so the product is `430000`, the expected answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sigfigs2(int n)
{
    return (n<100)? n : sigfigs2(n/10)*10;
}

int main(void) {
    int test[] = {438332, 56322, 1256489};
    
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(test)/sizeof(*test); ++i)
    {
        printf("%d ==> %d\n", test[i], sigfigs2(test[i]));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 5424KB
438332 ==> 430000
56322 ==> 56000
1256489 ==> 1200000
```

Answer (score -1):

A trivial example like this

```
int roundNum(int num) {
    int count = 0;
    while (num > 100) {
        num = ( num / 10 );
        count ++;
    }
    while (count > 0) {
        num *= 10;
        count --;
    }
}
```

FYI, this might be inefficient

Answer (score -2):

I think you can easily use %1d placeholder to only read first two digits and then use strategy of taking mod with 10 to get total number of digits

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).